# How to put authentication with apiKey in hapi-swagger?

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-ui, hapi.js

I have a node-project & I am using hapi framework along with joi & hapi-swagger. Its working fine & its generating API docs properly.
Now I need that *http://localhost:5000/documentation* url to be accessible only when I provide apiKey as a query-param. Basically I want authentication so that no one without apiKey will be able to access *http://localhost:5000/documentation*

The code I tried -

```
var swaggerOptions = {
  apiVersion: '2.0',
  auth: 'apiKey',
  authorizations: {
    apiKey : {
      type: 'apiKey',
      passAs: 'query',
      keyname: 'secret_password'
    }
  }
}

var server = new Hapi.Server()
server.connection({port: 5000})

server.route(<router>) //router contains all the routes

const scheme = function (server, options) {
  return {
    authenticate: function (request, reply) {
      if (request.query['secret_password'] !== 'XXX') {
        return reply(Boom.unauthorized('credentials failed'))
      }
      return reply.continue({credentials: {user: 'developer'}})
    }
  }
}
server.auth.scheme('custom', scheme)

server.register([inert, vision, {register:hapiSwagger, options:swaggerOptions}], function (err) {
      server.auth.strategy('apiKey', 'custom')
      server.start(callback)
    })
```

On running this it shows properly when secret_password is wrong but when its correct it just shows a word swagger referring to swagger.io link.

I searched but didn't get any information or example about this.
Am I missing something?

Comment: Does it work with `npm install hapi-swagger@3.0.0-rc1`? https://github.com/glennjones/hapi-swagger/issues/180

Comment: No. I tried with 3.0.0-rc1 here is my new swaggerOptions object.  `var swaggerOptions = {  
  //apiVersion: '2.0',  
  //auth: 'apiKey',  
  authorizations: [{  
    apiKey : {  
      type: 'apiKey',  
      passAs: 'query',  
      keyname: 'secret_password'  
    }]  
}`   It throws [1] "authorizations" is not allowed error.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue with authentication in v3.0.0-rc1 This version is a early release candidate of the new version under development. If you move back to the latest stable version v2.2.3 authentication should work.

Comment: I think the reason why you and other pick up the dev version is that the npm  publish was not tagged correctly. I am sorry if this has cause you problems. I have corrected this but had to bump the version to v2.2.4.

Please make sure you read the README.md file again. The options for hapi-swagger are different between v2.x and v3.x

Comment: I tried with v2.2.4 as well as v3.0.0-rc1 (making necessary changes to options) but the behaviour is same. Is there any example available anywhere for this? Unable to understand what am I doing wrong.